# Swagger UI is not displaying anything on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, swagger, swagger-ui, nodejs-server

I have developed Node.js App using Express framework and documented using "swagger-jsdoc" and "swagger-ui-express".
Swagger UI is loading on my "localhost:3000/v1/docs" and working properly.

Now, I deployed it to Amazon EC2 instance (Ubuntu, Linux), all API's are hitting and working properly but "myamazonurl.com/v1/docs" are redirecting to Swagger UI but not displaying anything.

I configured pm2 and nginx as well.

Errors coming in console and network are same and they are attached.

On first hit to the URL:

[image: On first hit to the URL]

On reloading the page:

[image: On reloading the page]

Is there any additional configuration or setup is required to run Swagger UI?
What is the issue?

I'll be thankful...

Answer (score 2):

just move the swagger configuration above the `app.use(helmet());` plugin :-

```
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerDocument = require('../swagger.json');
app.use('/v1/docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));

app.use(helmet());
```

it is forcing to find resources on https scheme, even if it's not configured yet.

Source: [Github](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/1006#issuecomment-825803215)